# Why Radio button selects multiple options when label values are different

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Having a reusable Radio button component, when the options are using the same value for `name` it works fine:

```
  const drinks = [
    {
      label: "Coffee",
      name: "a"
    },
    {
      label: "Tea",
      name: "a"
    },
    {
      label: "Water",
      name: "a",
      disabled: true
    }
  ];
```

But when they are different values, it doesn't work fine, it lets the user select multiple options:

```
  const drinks = [
    {
      label: "Coffee",
      name: "1"
    },
    {
      label: "Tea",
      name: "2"
    },
    {
      label: "Water",
      name: "3",
      disabled: true
    }
  ];
```

Here is a working sandbox of it as it's complicated to create a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-radio-button-group-forked-1do5u4?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: the name attribute is used to group radio buttons together
so, on your first example, they are `treated` as a single group, and only one radio button in the group can be selected at a time.

your second example, different name attributes., so they are not treated as single group, and thus you could select multiple radio buttons

Comment: Please include the code here, links tend to disappear

Comment: @Samuel is it possible to get rid of them without affecting the functionality?

Comment: @LeoMessi if you are talking about the name attribute, i am sure you can't ,  because it is used to define the group of radio buttons

Comment: @LeoMessi Again for clearance,
name attribute is used to group up radio buttons. nothing more

Answer (score 1):

It is working as expected. If it's a radio button, then it's ONE name and multiple possible values. Only one of them can be selected at a time.

```
  const drinks = [
  {
    label: "Coffee",
    name: "drinkType"
  },
  {
    label: "Tea",
    name: "drinkType"
  },
  {
    label: "Water",
    name: "drinkType",
    disabled: true
  }
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in comment,
the code is working as expected

```
const drinks = [
    {
      label: "Coffee",
      name: "a"
    },
    {
      label: "Tea",
      name: "a"
    },
    {
      label: "Water",
      name: "a",
      disabled: true
    }
  ];
```

the `name` attribute is used to group radio buttons,and only one radio button in the group can be selected at a time.